# PageViewController not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am integrating `PageViewController`. I am getting an error.

> Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x105390ca8) to 'VeggieIndia.PageContentViewController' (0x10273bc98).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrPagePhoto = ["background", "background", "3.jpg"];

    self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(index: 0)], direction: .forward, animated: true) { (true) in

    }

    self.dataSource = self

    //  self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex[0]] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController {
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
    pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"

    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    return pageContentViewController
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have set the ViewController class to `PageContentViewController` in your storyboard?

Comment: @egor.zhdan  Pls Have a look on it I am attaching image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the module if you looked under the class name in identity inspector you will find module is None , focus on class and click enter or check `Inherit Module From Target`